# Unable to access file generated by GhostScript in Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert PDF to JPEGs using GhostScript on AWS Lambda.

I've tried below code for the conversion.

```py
import os
pdf2img_conversion = os.system(
                "gs -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT "
                "-dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "
                "-sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r150 "
                "-sOutputFile=out_%d.jpg " + local_file_path
            )
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: **** Could not open the file out_1.jpg .
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --showpage--
Operand stack:
1 true
Execution stack:
%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 14 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 1745 0 9 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1141/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:21/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 30
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. 
I wasn't giving the full path for the output file path.

```
-sOutputFile=/tmp/out_%d.jpg
```

This did the trick.

Comment: @KenS How do I upgrade to GhostScript version in Lambda?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue whatever, sorry.